# How to search the string in multiple columns of relational table using Laravel whereRelation?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a relation in Space model,

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->withTrashed();
}
```

In my controller, I want to search string from two columns 'first_name' & 'last_name' which are in 'users' table.

But I didn't find the syntax to write "or" conditon in whereRelation.

```
$query = new Space();

$query = $query->with('user')->whereRelation('user', 'first_name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
```

How to search the string in multiple columns of relational table using whereRelation ?

Comment: Try add `orWhereRelation` after `whereRelation`, for the second table column.
https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_orWhereRelation

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1.** You can search from the two fields separately:

```php
Space::with('user')->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%');
});
```

**Option 2.** What I'm guessing you really want is to join the two fields together with a space in between and compare your search to that:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

// ...

Space::with('user')->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where(
        DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name)'),
        'LIKE',
        '%' . $request->search . '%'
    );
});
```